# Nvarchar to decimal and filter the result

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am having trouble making a query that converts nvarchar column to decimal and display only values that are are > 90, <90 and =90.

With query that I built, at first it seemed like it gives the desired result, but it doesn't. The column(Price) has both **null values** and **non numeric** values like 'red',abcde' etc.Also, the values in nvarchar column (price) has **1,2,3 or more numbers after the decimal point** like 90.0, 1234.5643, 34.00 etc.

Here is the query I wrote -

```
select * from PriceList A1 
join (
select * from  priceList
where ISNUMERIC(price) <>0)
     )A2
on A1.productId = A2.productId
and A1.ObjectKey=a2.ObjectKey
and CAST(A1.price as decimal(10,4)) > '90'
```

I get few rows back result and then there is an error -

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 2
>   Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric.

What is wrong with the query?

**Edited below**. This works except for =(equal to) condition I get 'Error converting nvarchar to numeric'. The error sis same for = 90 or = 900 etc. Wonder what's wrong now?!

```
select * from PriceList A1 
join 
( select * from PriceList where isnumerice(price)<>0 
and price like '%[^a-zA-z]%' ) A2 
on A1.productid = A2.productId and A1.ObjectKey=a2.ObjectKey 
where CAST(A1.convertedvalue as decimal(20,8)) > '90' 
and price like '%[^a-zA-z]%'
```

Comment: The error tells you.... you cant convert values like `red` and `abcde` to a numeric value as there not numeric.

Comment: It is not mandatory that inner query `where` clause should be executed before outer query `where` clause.

Comment: @Matt Indianso I have included thewhere clause in the outer query as well to filter out non numbers. The query is now is below -
select * from PriceList A1 join (
select * from 
PriceList 
where isnumerice(price)<>0
and price like  '%[^a-zA-z]%' 
) 
A2
on A1.productid = A2.productId and A1.ObjectKey=a2.ObjectKey
where CAST(A1.convertedvalue as decimal(20,8)) > '90'
and price like  '%[^a-zA-z]%'                                                                                        However when I want values ='90' I get 'error converting nvarchar to non numeric. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

It is because `CAST(A1.price as decimal(10,4))>90` is giving error for the non numeric values like 'red','abcde', etc

Try this

```
select * from
(
select A1.* from PriceList A1 
join (
select * from  priceList
where ISNUMERIC(price) <>0)
     )A2
on A1.productId = A2.productId
and A1.ObjectKey=a2.ObjectKey
and A1.price not like '%[^0-9]%' 
) as t where CAST(price as decimal(10,4)) > '90'
```

Comment: Ok. I thought so too. But referrign to my query, wouldn't the table A2 eliminate all the non numeric values including nulls?  Then the join result would be with only rows that have numeric values. That was my understanding. Can you please explain?

Comment: Referring to your query, I get the message 'The column 'productId' was specified multiple times for 't'.' I don't seem to  figure this out.

Comment: Modified your code in the like part to get only numbers.  I still have the 'error converting nvarchar data type to numeric'                             select * from
(
select A1.* from PriceList A1 
join (
select * from  priceList
where ISNUMERIC(price) <>0)
     )A2
on A1.productId = A2.productId
and A1.ObjectKey=a2.ObjectKey
and A1.price not like '%[a-zA-z]%' 
) as t where CAST(price as decimal(10,4)) > '90'

Answer (score 0):

Use a case statement any time you want to do a conversion, and then compare or do arithmetic with the converted value:

```
case 
when isnumeric(fieldname) = 1 then cast(fieldname as decimal(10,4)) 
else null end
```

So:

```
select * 
from  priceList
where case 
  when isnumeric(fieldname) = 1 then cast(fieldname as decimal(10,4)) 
  else null 
  end  > 90
```

Comment: Thanks, Ben! That worked like a charm. When you say'this type of a thing' can you explain?Why didn't the other query work for 'equal to' condition? Your query works for <> and =. The number of rows returned were same for both mine and your query for the < and > conditions.

Comment: by "this type of thing" I mean any time you want to do a conversion and then compare or do arithmetic with the converted value. I don't know why yours didn't work for = but I suspect it is because the condition `price like '%[^a-zA-z]%'` is wrong - it doesn't allow decimal point. You want to say `(price not like '%[0-9.]%' and price not like '%.%.%')` i.e. can contain at most one decimal point.

Comment: Got it! Thanks a lot! :)